# Browser unable to load theme.css.php file from magento skin folder

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

I am using Godday as hosting. I have used Gala Super Market Responsive Theme

I have tested in localhost it's working fine but when I have to try to install on the live hosting server, one of theme file is not loading.

```
[domain.com]/skin/frontend/default/galasupermarket/css/theme.css.php
```

Can anyone have faced this problem or can help me to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I got the answers:

When I comment the .htaccess file in root directory and remove the cache
then the file was work properly.